# jQuery Datepick (Keith Wood) highlight defaultDate with a CSS-class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I am using the inline version of Keith Woods jquery datepick plugin.
The default value for the picker is set like this:

```
var dpInputField = $('input#datepicker-value');
var defaultDate = (dpInputField.val() == '') ? '1399593600' : dpInputField.val(); // 1399593600 = 9th May 2014 00:00:00

    $('#datepicker').datepick({
      dateFormat: $.datepick.TIMESTAMP,
      monthsToShow: 2,
      changeMonth: false,
      altField: '#datepicker-value',
      onDate: showDayAndMonth,
      defaultDate: defaultDate,
    }, $.extend($.datepick.regional[window.language]));
```

Theres a form submit after selecting a date. If I debug the defaultDate its correct! Just a CSS-class is missing somehow.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/R46mk/1/

Comment: yeah becouse your not using the inline version. you are using the popout version

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I am using the onShow: event to call a function which is selecting the HTML object by its class.

for example: class="dp1403344800000", as theres the timestamp as part of the css class, it was no problem to .addClass(datepicker-selected)